# 128bit long doubles in ruby?

Tags: ruby, unpack, long-double

In my ruby code, I'm talking to a server that responds with 128bit long doubles ("128 bit long doubles", "binary128" or "[quadruple precision floating points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple_precision)") as strings in binary format.

Is there a way to unpack these strings for use in ruby? According to the documentation on [String.unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001112), the maximum precision seems to be doubles. Is it possible to represent these 128bit floats in ruby at all?